# Google App engine - submitting form field "field[key]"

Tags: python, google-app-engine

So my question is, how I can get form values as list when submitting this particular form:

```
<form action="/foobar" method="post">

<input type="text" value="text 1" name="text[key_1]" />
<input type="text" value="text 2" name="text[key_2]" />
<input type="text" value="text 3" name="text[key_3]" />
<input type="text" value="text 4" name="text[key_4]" />

</form>
```

Currently, you cannot get all this values as dict / touple / list using self.request.get('text') or self.request.get_all('text'), cause this only works if you exactly specify self.request.get('text[key_1]').

You can do this type of form:

```
<form action="/foobar" method="post">

<input type="text" value="text 1" name="text" />
<input type="text" value="text 2" name="text" />
<input type="text" value="text 3" name="text" />
<input type="text" value="text 4" name="text" />

</form>
```

texts = self.request.get_all('text') // you would get texts = ['text 1', 'text 2', 'text 3', 'text 4']

But like I said, I need key/pair form values

Comment: `x[y]` in forms is a rather odd PHP convention. You'd be better picking something better suited to parsing yourself. Or better, just use different names, which is kind of the point of named fields.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using webapp framework. To get key/value pairs. you can do something like this

if your method is GET,

```
self.request.str_GET.items()
```

else

```
self.request.str_POST.items()
```

More reference [here](http://pythonpaste.org/webob/reference.html#request-body)

Comment: the self.request.str_POST.items() would return key/pairs of post, but not the field[key]... [('question', ''), ('options', ''), ('options', ''), ('tags', ''), ('token', 'ejgTidm4iGXNgl0NpUQmWGeSU'), ('other[1]', '1'), ('other[2]', '2'), ('other[3]', '3'), ('other[4]', '4')] while the post who helped me returns {'1': '1', '3': '3', '2': '2', '4': '4'} as what i want